# InDesign Automated Tests

Tags: windows, vbscript, automation, jsx, adobe-indesign

Is there a way to create automated tests for InDesign in Windows?
For example:

- Open InDesign
- Open a Document
- Run a JSX Script
- Close file
- Close InDesign

From what I've researched I didn't find an straight forward way to do it. What I found was a mix of languages. VBScript with JSX. I had this with AppleScript instead of VBScript but it was messy. It could crash at any moment without an easy way of recover it.

Comment: I don't know vb script but got a lot of experience with AS/ASOC. If this is still an option show what you've got.

Comment: Hello Pat_Morita. I was able to use C# to get what I needed. I've posted here the solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to create an automated test using C#. Before I start I needed to do a couple of steps in order to have a good environment to develop.

This is the setup I used:

- Windows 10 Pro
- Visual Studio 2017 Pro (Trial)
- InDesign CC 2017

Now the steps of how I did it:

- Start InDesign as admin to create a file so I could use as reference in my Visual Studio Project
- Create a new Console project (This was my case)
- Add the COM Reference to the project. In the tab COM, you will find a reference to an Indesign tlb file
  [image: COM References]

Now to create an Indesign instance I used the following code:

```
Type inDesignAppType = Type.GetTypeFromProgID("InDesign.Application.CC.2017");
InDesign.Application myInDesign = (InDesign.Application)Activator.CreateInstance(inDesignAppType);
```

After this, to run an InDesign script I used:

```
String myString = myInDesign.DoScript("return \"My String\"", InDesign.idScriptLanguage.idJavascript, new object[] {""});
```

I hope my solution helps someone else.